# man causes a broken pipe when using a pager other than less

Tags: osx, man, less, pager

I'm trying to write a simple script to format my man pages, but I've run into a broken pipe error.

These lines both cause the error:

```
env MANPAGER=cat man $foo
man -P cat $foo
```

and this is the script I'm ultimately trying to use (converts underlines into italics)

```
man -P ul "$1" | sed -e $'s/\033\\[4m/\033\\[3m/g' -e $'s/\033\\[24m/\033\\[23m/g'
```

I get the same problem with `cat`, `ul`, and `tee`, and the only thing that seems to work is `less`.

Comment: This seems to work for me on Mac OS X (10.9.4) using iTerm (1.0.0.20140629).

bash-3.2$ man -P 'cat -b' less | tail -n 1
  1200                            Version 418: 02 Jan 2008                    LESS(1)

Comment: What error do you get? if I define foo=ls, then it seem to work for me. (using Debian 7). Can you add to the question the exact command and the error.

Comment: I've checked some more and this seems to be specifically an iTerm2 issue with non-interactive profiles… `echo` is causing it too.